# Plugin error: Plugin 'Google Sceneform Tools (Beta)' is compatible with IntelliJ IDEA only because it doesn't define any explicit module dependencies

Tags: android-studio, sceneform

I have install google sceneform, then i restart it shows me error like     "Plugin error: Plugin 'Google Sceneform Tools (Beta)' is compatible with IntelliJ IDEA only because it doesn't define any explicit module dependencies"   . But i need this google sceneform in my project

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Sceneform Tools are outdated since a few years now. Please switch to the new maintained version of Sceneform or Sceneview https://github.com/SceneView